# npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, installation

Even though Ive updated tar to version 8.3.1 it doesn't allow me to install react(`npm install -g create-react-app`). After I try to install react it outputs following message:

```
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 2s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details."
```

When I type `npm audit` it outputs that 0 vulnerabilities were found.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error. create-react-app uses exactly this version (2.2.2) of tar, even though it's outdated. You can install a new version of tar globally by running this command `npm install tar@latest -g` but since create-react-app uses other version you might still see that warning.

Answer (score 1):

Had the very same issue, I solved it by running directly the tool with `npx`, like this:

`npx create-react-app my-app-name`

Answer (score 0):

I added sudo at the start of my command and that solved the problem:

Try:

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```